# Implementing the function logBase2

Tags: haskell

I want to make a logBase2 function in Haskell that takes the result of 2^x then it returns the x but I've failed somehow...my code was

```
logBase2 :: Integral a => a -> a
logBase2 1 = 0
logBase2 n = 1 + (div n 2)
```

but it gets me some error results like if I put `logBase2 8` it gets me 5
How could I get that thing working perfectly?

Answer (score 5):

You need to make a *recursive* call with `div n 2`, so:

```
logBase2 :: Integral a => a -> a
logBase2 1 = 0
logBase2 n = 1 + logBase2 (div n 2)
```

otherwise the function will for a value for *n* return *1+(n/2)*.

By making a recursive call, we will retrieve `1 + 1 + 1 + 0`, so:

```
Prelude> logBase2 8
3
```